# Python Code Crashes with 'Pythonw.exe stopped working' but Works Fine in Debug Mode

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am dealing with a strange problem. I have some substantial code written in Python. When I run it in debug mode with PyCharm, it works fine. But it crashes in run mode in both Python IDLE and PyCharm IDE and a Windows dialog appears that says 'Pythonw.exe stopped working'.

I am using Python 2.6.6 in Windows 7 32-bit with PyCharm 2.5 as my IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is causing Python to crash?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unusual, are you using any extensions (written in C) that might cause the crash?

If you can get a stack trace from the crashed process you should be able to see if it crashes in external modules or something that comes with python. 
You could also try upgrading to the latest 2.7 version of python. If it is really a bug within python, there's a chance it has been fixed in the latest release.

Another thing to try is to try running it with PyPy, jython, IronPython (provided you don't need extensions that are unavailable on those platforms) and on other operating systems, which might give you some help in finding out where things go wrong.

Also, like Blender already said, if you could post some code that causes the problem, people might be able to help finding the problem.

Without more information it is hard to give better advice.

**Update:**
Just looked at the pythonocc you mentioned. It looks like it uses a lot c/c++ code so testing it on other python implementations or versions might not work all that well.
Since it seems like a bug somewhere, I'd suggest contacting the pythonocc guys to try to describe your problem and hopefully they'll fix it.

Comment: Tnx Dear Mattias; I use PythonOCC module that is a CAD kernel provided in Python classes. It is really an unusual for me. I don't know any way for for getting some trace because when I run it in debug mode, it works fine. I will test PyPy and Jython ASAP. You know, my code is about a CAD program and specific to Mechanical engineers and may be alittle different from usual software  engineers codes.

Comment: Dear Mattias; I have a question about difference between RUN and DEBUG modes. Can it be because of the high running speed of RUN in comparison with DEBUG? because the only thing that differs between these two is the speed of running. Am I right?

Comment: Run speed might be a difference, but it might also be other reasons. Typically, the python runtime itself won't crash, you have to get pretty creative to manage that, so my guess is that it's some extension that doesn't work properly.

Comment: Also, I'm terrible at windows, but I know that you can easily get stack traces from crashed processes (core files) on unix systems. It would surprise me if there wasn't a way to do something similar in windows.

Comment: Tnx for ur attention Mattias; there is a software named AppCrashView for windows that I installed and found that an error being occured in PyQt4 module and QtGui4.dll. I am going to work on that... do u have any suggestion? for example installing another version or...

Comment: SOLVED!

Tnx alot to Mattias for his valuable comments...

I installed PyQt4.5 for Python 2.6.6 and the error got resolved!